# Select Group in LayerTree using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, layertree

I create a script in order to make specific events according to the layers. I have already performed a sort according to the name of the layers. This is how I did it:

> ```
> keep_layer = ['layer1', 'layer2']
> for lay in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
>        for k_layer in keep_layer :
>            if lay.name() == k_layer :
>                #Do something
>            else:
>                pass
> ```

This sorting allows me to make precise modifications on the layers with the same name as those entered in the `keep_layer` variable.

I also created a variable `keep_group` which will have the groups for which I want to make changes. Here is the type of subgroup I'm trying to select (screenshot) :

[image: The sub-groups in question are framed in red]

I thought of something like the previous sort but I can't select the name of the subgroups.

```
keep_group = ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']
for lay in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        for k_group in keep_group :
            if lay.name() == k_group :
                for children in k_goup.children():
                    #Do something
            else:
                pass
```

How to select a subgroup according to its name in the LayerTree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it simply like this:

```py
group_names = ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for group in root.findGroups():
    if group.name() in group_names:
        #Do something...
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you! I didn't know about the existence of the `findGroups()` method before

Comment: You are most welcome! Glad it's what you were looking for.